# Is it possible to determine whether a variable is allocated on the stack or heap in swift (in SIL maybe)?

Tags: swift, memory-management, stack, heap-memory

I want to see if the structure "B" will be stored in the heap or in the stack when mixing value and reference types.

```
class A {}
struct B {
    var val = A()
}
var someVar = B()
```

I searched for information in memory graphs, but I didn't find anything.
I was running the command to print SIL representation:
`swiftc -emit-silgen -O main.swift`

But I don't understand the output

```
// B.init()
sil hidden [ossa] @$s4main1BVACycfC : $@convention(method) (@thin B.Type) -> @owned B {
// %0 "$metatype"
bb0(%0 : $@thin B.Type):
  %1 = alloc_box ${ var B }, var, name "self"     // user: %2
```

I thought alloc_box inform about allocating memory in the heap. But for the usual structure alloc_box is also used.

```
struct A {}
var someVar = A()
```

```
// A.init()
sil hidden [ossa] @$s4main1AVACycfC : $@convention(method) (@thin A.Type) -> A {
// %0 "$metatype"
bb0(%0 : $@thin A.Type):
  %1 = alloc_box ${ var A }, var, name "self"     // user: %2
```

Comment: It does not make sense to ask where an instance of `B` would be stored. You did not even create any instances of `B`. Different instances would be in difference places, depending on how you created them. In any case, Swift does not guarantee anything. An instance of a struct can be in the heap, and an instance of a class can be on the stack. IIRC instances could even be stored in registers if it is small enough.